# WordPress - File(/) is not within the allowed path(s)

Tags: php, wordpress, open-basedir, dirname

I have something really strange after moving an WordPress to my Server:

```
Wed Aug 27 18:10:43 2014] [warn] [client 77.21.106.179] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Warning: is_dir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/vhosts/xyz/:/tmp/:/usr/share/pear/) in /var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz/wp-includes/functions.php on line 1425
```

Why try's WordPress to Access /? Any ideas?

While calling WordPress an 1GB Err-Log will be generated ^^

I do host around 100 WP instances, all do very well, no install trys to Access '/'.

EDIT

This is the function wich Fails:

```
function wp_mkdir_p( $target ) {
    $wrapper = null;

    // strip the protocol
    if( wp_is_stream( $target ) ) {
        list( $wrapper, $target ) = explode( '://', $target, 2 );
    }

    // from php.net/mkdir user contributed notes
    $target = str_replace( '//', '/', $target );

    // put the wrapper back on the target
    if( $wrapper !== null ) {
        $target = $wrapper . '://' . $target;
    }

    // safe mode fails with a trailing slash under certain PHP versions.
    $target = rtrim($target, '/'); // Use rtrim() instead of untrailingslashit to avoid formatting.php dependency.
    if ( empty($target) )
        $target = '/';

    if ( file_exists( $target ) )
        return @is_dir( $target );


    // We need to find the permissions of the parent folder that exists and inherit that.
    $target_parent = dirname( $target );

    // MY MODIFICATION
    if ($target_parent = '/') {
        var_dump($target, $target_parent);
        die(debug_print_backtrace());
    }
    // MY MODIFICATION END

    while ( '.' != $target_parent && ! is_dir( $target_parent ) ) {
        $target_parent = dirname( $target_parent );
    }

    // Get the permission bits.
    $dir_perms = false;
    if ( $stat = @stat( $target_parent ) ) {
        $dir_perms = $stat['mode'] & 0007777;
    } else {
        $dir_perms = 0777;
    }

    if ( @mkdir( $target, $dir_perms, true ) ) {

        // If a umask is set that modifies $dir_perms, we'll have to re-set the $dir_perms correctly with chmod()
        if ( $dir_perms != ( $dir_perms & ~umask() ) ) {
            $folder_parts = explode( '/', substr( $target, strlen( $target_parent ) + 1 ) );
            for ( $i = 1; $i <= count( $folder_parts ); $i++ ) {
                @chmod( $target_parent . '/' . implode( '/', array_slice( $folder_parts, 0, $i ) ), $dir_perms );
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    return false;
}
```

I have added some modification, read the comments to find it, I get the following Output:

```
string(95) "/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2014/09"
string(1) "/" 
#0 wp_mkdir_p(/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2014/09) called at [/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-includes/functions.php:1743] 
#1 wp_upload_dir() called at [/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-content/themes/legatus-theme/functions/other.php:360] 
#2 require(/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-content/themes/legatus-theme/functions/other.php) called at [/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-includes/template.php:503] 
#3 load_template(/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-content/themes/legatus-theme/functions/other.php, ) called at [/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-includes/template.php:477] 
#4 locate_template(Array ([0] => functions/other.php), 1, ) called at [/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-includes/general-template.php:179] 
#5 get_template_part(functions/other) called at [/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-content/themes/legatus-theme/functions/init.php:9] 
#6 require(/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-content/themes/legatus-theme/functions/init.php) called at [/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-includes/template.php:503] 
#7 load_template(/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-content/themes/legatus-theme/functions/init.php, ) called at [/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-includes/template.php:477] 
#8 locate_template(Array ([0] => functions/init.php), 1, ) called at [/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-includes/general-template.php:179] 
#9 get_template_part(functions/init) called at [/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-content/themes/legatus-theme/functions.php:32] 
#10 include(/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-content/themes/legatus-theme/functions.php) called at [/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-settings.php:328] 
#11 require_once(/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-settings.php) called at [/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-config.php:111] 
#12 require_once(/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-config.php) called at [/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-load.php:29] 
#13 require_once(/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-load.php) called at [/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-blog-header.php:12] 
#14 require(/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-blog-header.php) called at [/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/index.php:17]
```

What is uncorrect, because dirname(/var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2014/09) should return /var/www/vhosts/xyz/xyz.kunden.xyz/wp-content/uploads/2014 and not just /...

any ideas?

Comment: Hi there,  You'd need to provide the code that's being called :)

Comment: what Kind of code? I call WordPress, doesn't matter if it's the front-page or wp-login.php ^^

Comment: I edited my code, please have a look

Answer (score 1):

Double-check that the path in `$target` really exists. This error happened to me after moving Wordpresses from one server to another, with different internal folder setups.

If the path in `$target` does not exist on your server, you need to correct every occurrence of it in the code and in the database.

In order to safely correct the values in the database, use a tool like https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB that takes care of dictionary-like structures in the database.